# 'Locale' configuration and its relationship with Windows API

Tags: windows, api, configuration, locale, createfile

Can the locale configuration of a system OR the keyboard type configuration of that system in anyway affect which API is called at the Kernel level? To be specific, if a program is invoking 'CreateFile()' API then the windows API documentation says that the call gets delegated to either CreateFileA or CreateFileW. If that program is being run on a system present in China with a Chinese Keyboard then which of the two functions will be called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unicode and Locale are two completely orthogonal concepts.

With regards to `CreateFileA` vs `CreateFileW` - the setting that controls this is a compile time setting: If the application is compiled to run with the Unicode character set, then `CreateFileW` will be called, if the compile settings indicated that the application should be compiled as a multibyte application, then `CreateFileA` will be called.

If you are using Visual Studio C++, then examine the Project settings of the application. Under Configuration Properties, on the page called "General" will be a setting "Character Set" - This can be set to "Use Unicode Character Set", or "Use Multi-Byte Character Set". The effect of this setting is to automatically add another property sheet to the solution - visible under the Property Manager: The "Unicode Support" property sheet adds the preprocessor definitions "`_UNICODE,UNICODE`" - the "Multi-Byte Character Support" property sheet instead adds "_MBCS".

Now, if you look at the definition for `CreateFile` you will see it is a macro itself, and when you build your application, all `CreateFile` calls in the code will resolve to `CreateFileW` calls if `UNICODE` is defined, and `CreateFileA` calls otherwise.

`UNICODE` is used by `windows.h` to switch between the Wide and Ansi versions of the windows API calls.

`_MBCS` and `_UNICODE` are used by the Microsoft C Runtime headers - principally tchar.h - to switch the c-library from supporting single byte to multi byte to unicode characters on functions that support that.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it cleared many of my doubts. Just to get your opinion on one more thing: If a well known product company is selling its product say in China or Saudi Arabia or Iran I would presume that they will be careful enough to compile the code by defining UNICODE right? Else there might be chances that the software would crash if the file-name uses Unicode character set, right? It would be really helpful if you could clarify this.

Comment: If you consult http://www.mydigitallife.info/ansi-code-page-for-windows-system-locale-with-identifier-constants-and-strings/ you can see that there are not a lot of unicode only locales. A person, living in China would, depending on their actual location, be quite able to develop a non-Unicode application, as long as all the characters in their file names could be encoded in the Chinese-traditional, or Simplified Chinese code pages.